# how to send hidden file to view of laravel (5.7)

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7, laravel-excel

I am creating an import function for import an excel file. the controller will handle it and save data to database.and after that,i want export the error to an excel file and send it to view. If the user clicks download, the excel file contains the error will download, otherwise do nothing.

So, I want to send a hidden file to the view to avoid saving the file to the database.

how to do it, please help!

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you're asking.. you say you're building an import function, but you're asking for help with exporting? Are you trying to validate the file before importing?

Comment: i want export after import. I want to export the errors in the client's import file

Comment: Are you looking to validate the header row of the import file? Or just that it's the correct file type?

Comment: Please edit your question properly, lacks readability

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane no, i want send an excel file to view, but users can choose to download it or not

Comment: @sadaiMudiNaadhar i edited it

Comment: What errors are you exporting? Why you are doing in this way? You can show errors during importing directly to view. Are you trying to write these errors to excel?

Comment: @sadaiMudiNaadhar Because if the data is too long and only some errors, instead of looking for errors and edit then the user can download the file containing errors and fix it

Comment: @themanhNguyen If you can give proper requirement about what all you need exactly then we can help. Its bit confusing about mentioning "data too long" stuffs like that. So please give us a proper requirement. If you created some mock codes post them also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after handle import in controller, you can pass error data to an array and send it to session like this:

```
$request->session()->put('err_file', $arr_err_data);
```

and create function to  get error file :

```
 public function getErrFile(){
        return Excel::create('Error', function ($excel){
            $excel->sheet('Error', function ($sheet) {
                $arr_err=Session::get('err_file');
                $sheet->fromArray($arr_err);
            });
        })->download('xlsx');
    }
```

Dont forget create route for this function:

```
Route::get('/get_err_file', 'YourController@getErrFile');
```

Final, you can create link to download it:

```
<a class="btn btn-link" href="{{url('get_err_file')}}" >Download</a>
```

I hope it can help you!